# WHERE clause before INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, where-clause

If I have

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.user='bob';
```

Does the `WHERE` clause run after the two tables are `JOINED`?

How do I make it so it runs prior to the JOIN?

Comment: The answers given are correct, but it's worth delving a little deeper. Why are you looking for this behavior? I'd imagine the query optimizer would handle the obvious case for you...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Change the `WHERE` to another `JOIN` condition

`LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id AND t1.user='bob'`

Answer (score 126):

The `where` clause will be executed before the `join` so that it doesn't join unnecessary records. So your code is fine the way it is.

Comment: @user1124535 I can confirm. Run the `explain` query and you'll see.

Comment: This is the better answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience in a left join you cannot exclude records in the 'left' (t1) table in the ON-statement since - by definition - all t1 records will be included. The where statement does work as it will be applied to the result of the join afterwards.

I do not exactly know what you want to achieve but most probably an inner join suits your needs as well and then you *can* add the t1.user='bob' condition to the ON-statement.

But if Mosty Mostacho is correct, the location (WHERE vs ON) of the condition is not relevant for speed of execution.

Answer (score 2):

What you may use is table expression after FROM like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
        id
    FROM Table1
    WHERE user = 'bob') AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just add `t1.user='bob'` condition to `ON` clause before other condition and it will be evaluated first:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.user='bob' AND t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```sql
SELECT * 
    FROM Table1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
        ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.user='bob';
```

Answer (score 0):

RIGHT JOIN was the solution:

```
SELECT cars.manufacturer, cars.year FROM cars 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT m.manufacturer FROM cars AS m ORDER BY m.year DESC LIMIT 3) subq 
ON cars.manufacturer=subq.manufacturer
```

Haven't put it through the full rigors yet, but seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

order of conditions in the ON clause has no impact. SQL query optimizer will evaluate and execute conditions in an optimized manner, regardless of their order

So

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.user = 'bob' AND t2.age = 25 AND t1.id = t2.id;
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.user = 'bob' AND t2.age = 25;
```

ARE SAME in terms of result and the query execution