# Can I include a where clause before Inner join clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have This code

```
$q = $conn->query("SELECT facultydetails.F_NAME,Paper_title from faculty inner join facultydetails on faculty.Fac_ID = facultydetails.Fac_ID where (paper_path = 'NULL' OR paper_path = '') and  (certificate_path = 'NULL' OR certificate_path = '') and (report_path = 'NULL' OR report_path = '') " );
```

Now I need to add a condition where a user will give the id and only That id related stuff should be picked can I use this code

```
$q = $conn->query("SELECT facultydetails.F_NAME,Paper_title from faculty where facultydetails.Fac_ID='$FacID' inner join facultydetails on faculty.Fac_ID = facultydetails.Fac_ID where (paper_path = 'NULL' OR paper_path = '') and  (certificate_path = 'NULL' OR certificate_path = '') and (report_path = 'NULL' OR report_path = '') " );
```

Working in php

Comment: I hope this will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133356/where-clause-before-inner-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a where before the inner join, but you can add your condition into the on clause, like:

```
"SELECT facultydetails.F_NAME,Paper_title ".
"from faculty ".
"inner join facultydetails ".
"on (facultydetails.Fac_ID='$FacID') and (faculty.Fac_ID = facultydetails.Fac_ID) ".
"where (paper_path = 'NULL' OR paper_path = '') and  (certificate_path = 'NULL' OR certificate_path = '') and (report_path = 'NULL' OR report_path = '') "
```

or you can prefilter your faculty table, like:

```
"SELECT facultydetails.F_NAME,Paper_title ".
"from (select * from faculty where (facultydetails.Fac_ID='$FacID')) f ".
"inner join facultydetails ".
"on f.Fac_ID = facultydetails.Fac_ID ".
"where (paper_path = 'NULL' OR paper_path = '') and  (certificate_path = 'NULL' OR certificate_path = '') and (report_path = 'NULL' OR report_path = '') "
```

EDIT:

In SQL having a code "above" or "below" some other part inside a single query will not guarantee that it is executed before it.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not add the where clause before the inner join.

Syntax for the inner join is as below:

```
SELECT column_list
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON join_condition1
INNER JOIN t3 ON join_condition2
...
WHERE where_conditions;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT facultydetails.F_NAME,Paper_title 
from faculty 
inner join facultydetails on faculty.Fac_ID = facultydetails.Fac_ID 
where facultydetails.Fac_ID='$FacID' 
AND (paper_path = 'NULL' OR paper_path = '') and  (certificate_path = 'NULL' OR certificate_path = '') and (report_path = 'NULL' OR report_path = '')
```

Comment: One SQL can only have one where clause you can use it as above