# Using filtered queries with joins with Quill

Tags: sql, scala

I have the following query:

```scala
for {
      post <- AllPosts
      result <- Likes
          .leftJoin(_.postId == post.id)
          .groupBy(_ => post.id)
          .map {
              case (_, likes) => (
                  post,
                  likes.size,
                  Likes.filter(l => l.postId == post.id && l.userId == lift(userId)).size > 0
              )
          }
  } yield result
```

but when I change `AllPosts` (which is `query[Post]`) to `ApprovedPosts` (which is `AllPosts.filter(_.isApproved)`) I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Found an `ON` table reference of a table that is not available: Set(x1). The `ON` condition can only use tables defined through explicit joins.
```

which is a bit too cryptic for me. Is there a way to reuse `ApprovedPosts`, or do I need to use `AllPosts` and repeat the filters explicitly? (The filter works if I put it after the `leftJoin`.)

Comment: The thing is happening when you use filter before join, is [WHERE clause before inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133356/where-clause-before-inner-join/10133436), Please read this and let me know if that helped :)